# One hot encoding of custom built vocabolary

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, one-hot-encoding

I have `charset` as follows.

```
charset =set([ '$', '^', '#', '(', ')', '-', '.', '/', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '=', 'Br', 
           'C', 'Cl', 'F', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'S', '[2H]', '[Br-]', '[C@@H]', '[C@@]', '[C@H]', '[C@]', 
           '[Cl-]', '[H]', '[I-]', '[N+]', '[N-]', '[N@+]', '[N@@+]', '[NH+]', '[NH2+]', '[NH3+]', '[N]', 
           '[Na+]', '[O-]', '[P+]', '[S+]', '[S-]', '[S@+]', '[S@@+]', '[SH]', '[Si]', '[n+]', '[n-]', 
           '[nH+]', '[nH]', '[o+]', '[se]', '\\', 'c', 'n', 'o', 's', '!', 'E'])
```

On the basis of this `charset`, I create `char_to_int`  as follows.

```
char_to_int = dict((c,i) for i,c in enumerate(charset))
```

> {'[nH]': 0,  '[2H]': 1,  '2': 2,  'N': 3,  'Cl': 4,  'c': 5,  '$': 6,
> 'O': 7,  '(': 8,  '6': 9,  's': 10,  '[S@+]': 11,  '[C@@H]': 12,  'C':
> 13,  '[nH+]': 14,  '/': 15,  '[NH+]': 16,  '[Br-]': 17,  '[Si]': 18,
> '4': 19,  '[N@+]': 20,  '[se]': 21,  'P': 22,  '[SH]': 23,  '[N+]':
> 24,  '[N]': 25,  '^': 26,  '5': 27,  '7': 28,  'n': 29,  '!': 30,
> '\': 31,  '[n-]': 32,  'S': 33,  '[NH3+]': 34,  '#': 35,  'I': 36,
> '[O-]': 37,  '1': 38,  '[NH2+]': 39,  '[S@@+]': 40,  'Br': 41,  'F':
> 42,  '[Na+]': 43,  'E': 44,  '[S-]': 45,  '.': 46,  ')': 47,  '[C@]':
> 48,  '=': 49,  '3': 50,  '-': 51,  '[C@H]': 52,  '[Cl-]': 53,  '[I-]':
> 54,  '[H]': 55,  '[P+]': 56,  '[S+]': 57,  'o': 58,  '[N@@+]': 59,
> '[N-]': 60,  '[n+]': 61,  '[o+]': 62,  '[C@@]': 63}

and `int_to_char` as follows.

```
int_to_char = dict((i,c) for i,c in enumerate(charset))
```

> {0: '[nH]',  1: '[2H]',  2: '2',  3: 'N',  4: 'Cl',  5: 'c',  6: '$',
> 7: 'O',  8: '(',  9: '6',  10: 's',  11: '[S@+]',  12: '[C@@H]',  13:
> 'C',  14: '[nH+]',  15: '/',  16: '[NH+]',  17: '[Br-]',  18: '[Si]',
> 19: '4',  20: '[N@+]',  21: '[se]',  22: 'P',  23: '[SH]',  24:
> '[N+]',  25: '[N]',  26: '^',  27: '5',  28: '7',  29: 'n',  30: '!',
> 31: '\',  32: '[n-]',  33: 'S',  34: '[NH3+]',  35: '#',  36: 'I',
> 37: '[O-]',  38: '1',  39: '[NH2+]',  40: '[S@@+]',  41: 'Br',  42:
> 'F',  43: '[Na+]',  44: 'E',  45: '[S-]',  46: '.',  47: ')',  48:
> '[C@]',  49: '=',  50: '3',  51: '-',  52: '[C@H]',  53: '[Cl-]',  54:
> '[I-]',  55: '[H]',  56: '[P+]',  57: '[S+]',  58: 'o',  59: '[N@@+]',
> 60: '[N-]',  61: '[n+]',  62: '[o+]',  63: '[C@@]'}

I have a string which I want to convert to one hot encoding on the basis of `char_to_int` and `int_to_char`.

```
string = 'N[C@H]1C[C@@H](N2Cc3nn4cccnc4c3C2)CC[C@@H]1c1cc(F)c(F)cc1F'
```

Is there any efficient way which uses the self defined `char_to_int` and `int_to_char` to convert a `string` to one hot vector?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, islice
import re

string = 'N[C@H]1C[C@@H](N2Cc3nn4cccnc4c3C2)CC[C@@H]1c1cc(F)c(F)cc1F'

items_list=[ '$', '^', '#', '(', ')', '-', '.', '/', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '=', 'Br', 
       'C', 'Cl', 'F', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'S', '[2H]', '[Br-]', '[C@@H]', '[C@@]', '[C@H]', '[C@]', 
       '[Cl-]', '[H]', '[I-]', '[N+]', '[N-]', '[N@+]', '[N@@+]', '[NH+]', '[NH2+]', '[NH3+]', '[N]', 
       '[Na+]', '[O-]', '[P+]', '[S+]', '[S-]', '[S@+]', '[S@@+]', '[SH]', '[Si]', '[n+]', '[n-]', 
       '[nH+]', '[nH]', '[o+]', '[se]', '\\', 'c', 'n', 'o', 's', '!', 'E']

charset = set(items_list)
char_to_int = dict((c,i) for i,c in enumerate(charset))

pattern = '|'.join(re.escape(item) for item in items_list)


tokens = re.findall(pattern, string)
x=[char_to_int[k] for k in tokens]
```

Here, `x`is one hot encoded.

```
x=[3, 52, 38, 13, 12, 8, 3, 2, 13, 5, 50, 29, 29, 19, 5, 5, 5, 29, 5, 19, 5, 50, 13, 2, 47, 13, 13, 12, 38, 5, 38, 5, 5, 8, 42, 47, 5, 8, 42, 47, 5, 5, 38, 42]
```